# Automatic Overnight Execution of R Scripts on Mac

Tags: macos, r, automation

I want to automate overnight execution of some R scripts in order to have the latest data when I start working. Can you guys tell me how to do that? Via AppleScript or the Automator? or other tools?

Ideally, I would get a sample code looking something like this (AppleScript)

tell R.app
execute example.r
at 2:00 every day

Thx for your help
Andreas

Comment: Id just use `cron`with a shell script. I dont know much about R, but i assume i can be executed from the CLI like anything else.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cron` combined with `Rscript` to do this.

First create an R script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env Rscript
print("Hello World!")
```

And save it as `print_hw.R`. Then enter at the terminal:

```
crontab -e
```

and choose a time to run the script:

```
 0 0 * * * print_hw.R
```

This runs the script every night at twelve o'clock. This all is under the assumption that `print_hw.R` can be executed (use `chmod`) and the script is in your `PATH`.

Comment: Isn't it launchd in the meantime? Can somebody provide me with a sample code how it works there?

Comment: @user2157086 I am not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Well, to my knowledge cron has been replaced by launchd. When I did as you suggested, I got the following message from the terminal "crontab: no crontab for anhomberger - using an empty one". What does this tell me? And what is chmod?

Comment: The message means that your crontab has been empty up until now, and a new one is created. This is normal. chmod is a command line tool to change the permissions of a file, e.g. make it executable. Have a look at `man crontab` and `man chmod` and google around some for those tools to get more information.